# Attach Debugger - The breakpoint will not be currently hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, debugging, azure, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to debug code deployed on Azure Websites by attaching debugger. When I put breakpoint anywhere in code, this displays similar error as given in the image.

```
The breakpoint will not be currently hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.
```

[image]

When I debug locally this works totally fine. I see ton of suggested answers while posting here but none of them helped me. As I said, debugging works locally totally okay but not by attaching debugger.

Development Environment: Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise on Windows 10.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What have you specifically done to attach to the remote website instance hosted in Azure?

Comment: have you deployed your `debug` build or `release` build.

Comment: @Malli1246 of-course deployed in release? Is that correct way?

Comment: @TimBarrass Created MVC Web App in Visual Studio > created a azure website using portal and downloaded publish profile > used this publish profile to publish on azure > while publishing I selected release build. And when attaching debugger I tried build as well as release.

Comment: @AbhimanyuKumarVatsa so, while attaching debugger, did you selected remote debugging?

Comment: @AbhimanyuKumarVatsa in general, Release build is having configuration to disable debugging unless you explicitly enable it. Also, if .pdb file is not available you will not be able to debug

Comment: @Malli1246 yes when project is opened in VS, I right clicked on azure website listed in azure explorer and then selected 'Attach Debugger' option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94318/discussion-between-abhimanyu-kumar-vatsa-and-malli1246).

Comment: please see the chat window. You can either change the web.release.config to enable debugging, or deploy a debug build to Azure and debug

Comment: Make sure you have the correct .Net version selected in the `Attach to` field of the `Attach to Process`. If you don't, it'll attach but will silently do nothing and breakpoints you add after attaching will show no symbols loaded. I just ran into this.

Answer (score 4):

please run following with admin command prompt.

C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd list wp

It will list w3wp processes ids with their application pool name. Run Visual Studio with Admin, and open your project, press ctrl+alt+p and attach w3wp from list with the id displayed in command prompt.

Make sure you build your application in Debug mode as shown below.
[image]
And also at page level also please specify Debug="true".

Comment: Are you sure this will help in remote debugging because this works very well locally already ?